# Convert result from a left join to an array (or json or whatelse)

Tags: php, mysql

I actually have these tables :

```
- Table games -
ID
Name

- Table ean -
ID
ID_games
EAN
```

And I have this request :

```
SELECT games.*, ean.EAN
FROM games
LEFT JOIN ean ON (games.ID = ean.ID_games)
```

The result will be something like this :

```
| 1 | Half Life | 358958595 |
| 1 | Half Life | 589584859 |
| 2 | Half Life 2 | 385953684 |
| 2 | Half Life 2 | 585100335 |
etc.
```

When I do my request and use it in php, it is not useful to have a lot of line with about the same results. I would like to do something like this :

```
SELECT games.*, ConvertToArray(ean) AS ean_array
FROM games
LEFT JOIN ean ON (games.ID = ean.ID_games)
```

And have results like this :

```
| 1 | Half Life | (358958595,589584859) |
| 2 | Half Life 2 | (385953684,585100335 ) |
etc.
```

Is it possible to that with mysql ? Without an UDF ? And with an UDF ?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you object to using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)? This would give you a nice delimited list (Assuming the `ean` value will never have your delimiter within):

```
SELECT       games.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ean.EAN) AS ean_list,
FROM         games
  LEFT JOIN  ean
  ON         games.ID = ean.ID_games
GROUP BY     games.ID, games.name
```

Resulting in:

```
| 1 | Half Life   | 358958595,589584859 |
| 2 | Half Life 2 | 385953684,585100335 |
```

Also, here's a qeustion I found with this logic applied: [mySql - creating a join using a list of comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120580/mysql-creating-a-join-using-a-list-of-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score 2):

See [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Example can be found [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat-with-distinct.php).

Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT games.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ean) AS ean_array
FROM games
LEFT JOIN ean ON (games.ID = ean.ID_games)
GROUP BY games.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT g.id, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(e.ean AS CHAR) SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN ean e ON g.id = e.id_games
GROUP BY g.id;
```