# Get record matching on both table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have following table structure

```
Table 1                  Table 2
----------             -------------------
Id  value              Id   ids    value
1   item1              1    1,3    Item1
2   item2              2    2,1    Item2
3   item3              3    1,3,5  Item3
4   item4              4    1      Item4
5   item5              5    2,1    Item5
```

Now I want to get all record from table 2 value which match from table 1 e.g. Id from table 1 matches ids from table 2

I want result like this

```
table1.value           table2.value
item1                  Item1
item1                  Item2
item1                  Item3
item1                  Item4
item1                  Item5
item2                  Item2
item2                  Item5
item3                  Item1
item3                  Item3
item5                  Item3
```

I have use following query

```
SELECT table1.value, table2.value FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id IN (table2.ids)
```

But not getting out put as I mentioned above. Any Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120580/mysql-creating-a-join-using-a-list-of-comma-separated-values

Comment: take this opportunity to fix the table definition. it is not a good idea to store comma separated id values in a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is evidence of a bad data structure.  Your data should be stored using an association table rather than a list.  But you can do this as:

```
select t1.value, t2.value
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on find_in_set(t1.id, t2.ids) > 0;
```

An alternative way of phrasing this is using `like`.  This idea works in any database, although the string concatenation differs:

```
select t1.value, t2.value
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on concat(',', t2.ids, ',') like concat('%,', t1.id, ',%')
```